# General questions about PDE programming

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pde

Here are two short, but hopefully good questions:

1. When to use plugins and when fragments?
2. What is a headless PDE build and when to use it (and when not)?

Comment: You will get better answers if you split your question in two separate ones.

Comment: thanks but doesn't it look kinda cheap to ask just a single line question? :D

Comment: Not at all. It makes it easier for people to answer and easier for others to understand what you are asking. Right now, your title doesn't say much.

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are for when you want to expand or alter the functionality of a plugin. A fragment cannot exist on it's own, it requires a parent plugin. The typical example of a fragment are for localizing a plugin, i.e to change strings to other languages. The fragment will then alter the functionality of the plugin to replace resources or code with the contents of the fragment.

[More details here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_a_plug-in_fragment?) [Tutorial here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseFragmentProject/article.html)

The headless part means you do the build without a gui, i.e from commandline or from a tool such as jenkins/hudson. PDE stands for Plugin Development Environment. In short, it adds some tasks to Ant, and you can use the defined resources and dependencies in the plugin.xml to build. The alternative is to again define classpaths, sources, etc in an Ant build file.

I've used it in some projects and it has been difficult to setup properly, but its the best way to build Eclipse plugins or products. We wanted to use relative paths for the build and had major problems with that. The earlier in your project that you set up a continous headless PDE build, the easier it will be to configure.

[More info here](http://owenou.com/2010/09/19/how-to-set-up-and-run-pde-build.html)